# counter function always show same value

Tags: python, pine-script, trading

i am using a public available script for finding rsi divergences .So there are 2 candles that we want to find divergence between them ... but i cant find the bar index(i mean how many candles has passed from it) of the first point. However i can find the rsi value of the first point by using Y=ta.valuewhen(plFound, rsi[lbR], 1) in the code below... then i have used "barssince" and "for" loop to see when the rsi was equal to Y but none of them work properly. can someone explain me why ?

```
//@version=5  
indicator(title="RSI Divergence Indicator w/Alerts", format=format.price,overlay=true)
len = input.int(title="RSI Period", minval=1, defval=14)
src = input.source(title="RSI Source", defval=close)
lbR = input.int(title="Pivot Lookback Right", defval=5)
lbL = input.int(title="Pivot Lookback Left", defval=5)
rangeUpper = input.int(title="Max of Lookback Range", defval=60)
rangeLower = input.int(title="Min of Lookback Range", defval=5)
plotBull = input.bool(title="Plot Bullish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input.bool(title="Plot Hidden Bullish", defval=false)
plotBear = input.bool(title="Plot Bearish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input.bool(title="Plot Hidden Bearish", defval=false)
rsi = ta.rsi(src, len)

plot(rsi, title="RSI", linewidth=2, color=#8D1699)
hline(50, title="Middle Line", linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
obLevel = hline(70, title="Overbought", linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
osLevel = hline(30, title="Oversold", linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
fill(obLevel, osLevel, title="Background", color=#9915FF, transp=90)

plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(rsi, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(rsi, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish
// Osc: Higher Low

oscHL = rsi[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, rsi[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low

priceLL = low[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

plot(
     plFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bullish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )
Y=ta.valuewhen(plFound, rsi[lbR], 1)     
plot(Y,color=color.yellow,offset=-lbR)// THIS SHOWS THE RSI'S FIRST POINT VALUE

q=0
if bullCond
    for i=0 to 50
        q:=q+1
        if ta.rsi(close,14)[i]==Y
            break
            
plot(bullCond?q:na,color=color.orange,offset=-lbR)// IT ALWAYS SHOWS 51 !
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of recalculating rsi , you should use the already calculated rsi.
So change this.

```
if ta.rsi(close,14)[i]==Y
```

To

```
if rsi[i]==Y
```

Comment: ooh, Thanks. but why there should be a problem with that?

Comment: Because you are calling it only on bullcondition. And so it will calculate that rsi and save its previous values in timeseries only on those cases. So it will not have the Y value in that series . So it is running full iteration of for loop till 50 and showing last value as 51